# Insert с Select

Tags: sql, mysql

Подскажите пример, когда в запросе INSERT применить SELECT.
Например:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (field_1, field_2) VALUES(V, VALUE_FIELD_FROM_SELECT)
SELECT VALUE_FIELD_FROM_SELECT FROM TABLE2 WHERE ID = 3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (field_1, field_2) 
SELECT V, VALUE_FIELD_FROM_SELECT FROM TABLE2 WHERE ID = 3;
```

[INSERT](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_operator_insert.html)

Comment: Т.е. остальные `VALUES` будут в `SELECT FIELDS`?

Comment: Да. Где взять еще символов.