# SQL INSERT: как вставить данные из другой таблицы?

Tags: sql

Мне нужно вставить новую запись в таблицу. Назовём её `task(id, task_type_id)`. Есть другая таблица, `task_type(id, name)`.

Как мне при добавлении записи в таблицу `task` взять одним запросом id нужной записи из таблицы `task_type` по полю name?

То есть, запрос по логике такой:

```
INSERT INTO task(task_type_id)
VALUES(<id, который соответствует такому-то полю name таблицы task_type);
```

Comment: вместо фразы values используете обычный запрос select, который возвращает требуемые для вставки данные (в вашем случае id)

Comment: спасибо. а как в том же запросе вставить ещё и статические данные?

Comment: `select id, 'статические данные' from ...`

Comment: спасибо. Не могли бы Вы оформить свои комментарии в ответ, чтобы я мог их принять?

Comment: С вопросами по SQL одна беда, пока не знаешь ответ найти аналогичный на SO практически не реально, хотя из сотни ... вот, будем читать, что этот похож ...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Insert с Select](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/369283/insert-%d1%81-select)

Comment: Он похож, но немного не то делает\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример:

```
INSERT INTO task(id, task_id)
VALUES (1000, (SELECT task_type.id FROM task_type WHERE task_type.id = 10000));
```